# Is there any way to call metamask from my own chrome extension?

Tags: metamask, infura

I'm trying to build myself a little expension to help me deal with my transactions and I can't figure out how to send transactions to metamask or open it from the chrome extension.

Apparently you need to have your html hosted on any tipe of server for metamask to run on it. Since chrome extension are not 'hosted' (if that is even the term) I can't acces window.ethereum.

The only thing I got going is, by using INFURA, getting the number of block, etc etc.

How should I set it up to be able do it? I would like to keep the extension if posible.